# I want to disable the button even after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an array of objects of named people. I am trying to disable the button should remain disabled even after refreshing the page. Pls help

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of people">
      <button [disabled]="item.disabled"(click)="item.disabled=true">Hi</button> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Then you need to save and fetch the `people` using for example `localStorage`.

Comment: can you post people JSON and are you using any backend?

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing the page is analogous to restarting your single page web application. When you refresh, your components and object states are reseted by default.
If you want an object state to survive a refresh, you simply need to store it via local or session storage or fetch it from an external service at OnInit

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of people">
  <button  mat-stroked-button color="primary" [disabled]="item.disabled" (click)="disableItem(item)">Hi</button>      
</div>

<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Section {
  name: string;
  updated: Date;
}

/**
 * @title List with sections
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-sections-example',
  styleUrls: ['list-sections-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'list-sections-example.html',
})
export class ListSectionsExample {
  people: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Photos',
      updated: new Date('1/1/16'),
    },
    {
      name: 'Recipes',
      updated: new Date('1/17/16'),
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.people = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('people'));
  }

  reset() {
    this.people = [
      {
        name: 'Photos',
        updated: new Date('1/1/16'),
      },
      {
        name: 'Recipes',
        updated: new Date('1/17/16'),
      }
    ];
    localStorage.setItem('people', JSON.stringify(this.people))
  }

  disableItem(data) {
    data.disabled = true;
    localStorage.setItem('people', JSON.stringify(this.people))
  }
}
```

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7wtmh)